# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sqlserver.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I'm trying to connect with MS SQL Server using a Java Application. This is the code I'm using:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    try {  
        Class.forName("com.sqlserver.jdbc.Driver");                                   
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver:<SERVER>","user","password");  
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();  
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT TOP 1 [MsgTextArabic] FROM 
     [FactBulkSMS].[dbo].[Messages] order by SendingDateTime desc");

        while(rs.next())  
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+""+rs.getString(2)+""+rs.getString(3));
    }
    catch(Exception e) { 
        System.out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When running this code, the following Exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sqlserver.jdbc.Driver

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sqlserver.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at test.main(test.java:13)
```

Comment: did you included required jars ?

Comment: There is no such driver, the correct driver is `"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"`. Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Exception is complaining, that `Class.forName("com.sqlserver.jdbc.Driver");` is unable to find the JDBC driver.

According to the Docs, you need to add the path where you put the driver into the ClassPath Variable. From Eclipse this can be done by importing the `.jar` files into the project and referencing them.

Source and further information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/connect/jdbc/using-the-jdbc-driver

Comment: You might want to mention that there is no such driver class, and that the correct class is `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the JVM can not find the class `com.sqlserver.jdbc.Driver`, this is most likely because the JAR has not been included in your project's classpath.

Since you are using eclipse I would recommend adding the JAR via Eclipse's "build path".

Start by checking which is the correct JAR for your set-up from the Microsoft docs [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/connect/jdbc/using-the-jdbc-driver)
You can then download the JAR from the [Maven repo](http://search.maven.org/)

Then inside Eclipse, Right click your project >> Build Path >> Configure Build Path. Select the Libraries tab, then on the right column click on, "Add External JARs"

Comment: You might want to mention that there is no such driver class, and that the correct class is `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`